# How do I return a user back to the page they came from after filling out a contact form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a website in VB/asp.net 4 and a client may be on a page that says "contact an engineer" and it brings you to a contact form.  After filling out the form, it says:

*Your message has been sent.  Thank you for contacting USS Vision.  A member of the engineering team at USS Vision will respond to you at the earliest convenience.*

I want to add a hyperlink saying "Return to the page you came from" and have them click it and go back to that page.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?  Thanks for any help anybody can offer!

Comment: What do you have so far (in code)?

Comment: Hello Alerty, and thank you for taking the time to respond.  I have nothing yet; upon completion of the form, it gives them that message.  But I'd like to add a hyperlink ..... something like javascript (goback -2) or something, however that should be coded.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [`document.referrer`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) or [`window.history`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp) can help you.

**UPDATE:**

Based on comments to this answer I'm also suggesting to retrieve [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)
when user comes and save it in Session, then use it anywhere you need.

Comment: Thank you for responding and for that link, Evgeniy.  I'm giving it a try right now, and I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: Hello Eveniy.  I tried the document.referrer.  My contact form is contactengineering.aspx and upon completion, it remains on contactengineering.aspx .... so it just refers it back to the contact form.  But what I really want is for there to be a hyperlink that refers the client 2 pages ago, from where they clicked the contact engineering link. So if they were on a page, say, robotguidance.aspx when they clicked the link, I'd like the hyperlink to point them back to that page. Thank you again for your time in responding, and I'll keep working on it!

Comment: So when users comes to robotguidance.aspx from somewhere, remember document.referrer to use it later at contactengineering.aspx.
Or just even remember HttpRequest.UrlReferrer in session when user comes to robotguidance.aspx.

Comment: Hello Evgeniy.  I solved the issue by using the following javascript code:  <a href="javascript: window.history.go(-2)">return to the page you came from</a>.  Thank you again for taking the time to help!

Comment: Just wanted to add the information about the `window.history`.

Comment: By the way I would suggest you to not use constructions like `href="javascript:...`, but to do it like `<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-2); return false;">return to the page you came from</a>`

Comment: Okay, I made that change and it worked perfectly!  Thanks again for your help Evgeniy!

Comment: Dim MyUrl As Uri = Request.UrlReferrer
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Port: " & Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Port.ToString()) & "<br>")
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Protocol: " & Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Scheme) & "<br>")       I would put this in the code behind on the contactengineering.aspx.vb?  Would I replace MyUrl with contactengineering.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some compelling reason to have them leave the page they're on, it'd probably be easiest -- and a better user experience -- to handle that by opening the contact form in a modal window; the user fills out the form, submits it, receives an acknowledgment, and closes the modal, no muss no fuss.

Comment: THank you ultranaut for responding.  As I mentioned to @Evgeniy Naydenov, I just used the following javascript, and it does the trick: <a href="javascript: window.history.go(-2)">return to the page you came from</a>.  Thanks again!